# saving a record after deletion

Tags: ms-access

I have a form to add a record for my users. The database will automatically add an ID to the record, after it's added with the user clicking a button on the form.

I also have a user activity log. I want to record the record's automatically generated ID number when the form adds a record. How do I access that number from the onClick event of the form?

```
Private Sub btnAddTax_Click()
    Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "INSERT INTO tblMain ( field1, field2,... )" _
        & "SELECT Forms![field1Box], Forms![field2Box],...;"

    DoCmd.RunSQL SQL

    MsgBox "Tax Added to the Database"
    DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMainScreen"
    DoCmd.Close acForm, Me.Name

    Dim tempString As String
    tempString = "Added a record"
    Logging (tempString)

End Sub
```

Comment: Edit question to post code for adding record.

Answer (score 0):

Consider code in button click event:

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
Debug.Print Me!ID 'or do something else with ID
```

Comment: Tried this, it returned "1". The autonumber was 2887.

Comment: Well, it works for me. However, am not opening another form nor calling another procedure. No other code, just the two lines shown. Suggest you test that before implementing in expanded code.

Comment: I'm just gonna append it to my user activity log first before putting it in the database